# Nuxt auth-next with keycloak CORS problem

Tags: oauth, nuxt.js, keycloak, nuxt-auth

Versions:

```
keycloak 12.0.2
nuxt: 2.14.6 
nuxt/auth-next: 5.0.0-1622918202.e815752
```

Configs:

nuxt.config.js

```
    auth: {
        strategies: {
            keycloak: {
                scheme: '~/plugins/keycloak.js',
                endpoints: {
                  authorization:'https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
                  token:'https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token',
                  userInfo: "https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                  logout:'https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/logout',
                },
                responseType: 'id_token token',
                clientId: 'centuari-portal-fe',
                scope: ['openid'],
              }
        },
        redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            logout: '/logout',
            callback: '/callback',
            home: '/',
          }
    },
    router: {
      middleware: ['auth']
    },
```

due to a [issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/559) with current version nuxt/auth-next, I created a custom scheme by extending oauth2

/plugin/keycloak.js

```
import { Oauth2Scheme } from '~auth/runtime'

function encodeQuery(queryObject) {
    return Object.entries(queryObject)
        .filter(([_key, value]) => typeof value !== 'undefined')
        .map(([key, value]) => encodeURIComponent(key) + (value != null ? '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) : ''))
        .join('&')
}

export default class KeycloakScheme extends Oauth2Scheme {
    logout() {
        if (this.options.endpoints.logout) {
            const opts = {
                client_id: this.options.clientId,
                post_logout_redirect_uri: this._logoutRedirectURI
            }
            const url = this.options.endpoints.logout + '?' + encodeQuery(opts)
            window.location.replace(url)
        }
        return this.$auth.reset()
    }
}
```

but when doing login,  browser will block the token request due to CORS. keycloak server response for the preflight specify allowed method is `POST, OPTIONS`, but auth-next use `GET` to fetch token.

Is there any work around ?

Comment: CORS is related to the backend or the service that you're using for the auth, here you need to whitelist `localhost` and your `production` URLs.

Comment: `GET` to fetch token? Really, https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest - I would use library, which follows OIDC specification (so `POST` for token request). I bet that Keycloak will reject that GET request when you resolve CORS problem.

Comment: I do have `POST` to fetch my JWT tokens, while using `nuxt-auth`. Didn't changed the configuration on this point AFAIK. Maybe `tokenRequired: true, tokenType: 'JWT',` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/register the url into keycloak admin dashboard.

1. Go to keycloak admin dashboard
2. Menu `Clients` => select the client
3. On `Settings` tab, scroll down the page and find `Web Origins`. Add your frontend url (nuxt url) on it. Don't forget to add into `Valid Redirect URIs` too.